# C# Linq - Combobox not filled

Tags: c#, linq, combobox

I have a problem with the `comboBoxContainer`. While `comboBoxategory` and `comboBoxMarket` are filled, `comboBoxContainer` is not filled.
`selected.Container` has the right variable but the combobox doesn't get this variable.

```
private void listBoxProducts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ProductList_Variables selected = ProductList_Variables)listBoxProducts.SelectedItem;

        textBoxProduct.Text = selected.Product;
        comboBoxCategory.SelectedItem = selected.Category;
        comboBoxMarket.SelectedItem = selected.Market;
        comboBoxContainer.SelectedItem = selected.Container;
        textBoxPrice1.Text = selected.Price.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
class ProductList_Variables
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Market { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get { return Product + " - " + Category + " - Size: " + Size +", Market: "+ Market; } }
    public string Flavour { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Container { get; set; }
    public int IdContainer { get; set; }


}
void Fillcombo()// is filling the combobox
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new GelatoProjectDBEntities())
        {
            var products = (from x in db.ProductsLists
                            select new ProductList_Variables { Id = x.Id, Product = x.Product, Category = x.Category, Size = x.Size, Market = x.Market, Container=x.Container, Price=x.Price, IdContainer=x.IdContainer }
                            ).OrderBy(c => c.Product).ToArray();
            listBoxProducts.Items.AddRange(products);
            listBoxProducts.DisplayMember = "ProductName";
            listBoxProducts.ValueMember = "Id";
            var goods = (from x in db.Goods
                         select new ProductList_Variables { Id = x.Id, Product=x.item, Container = x.item}
                         ).OrderBy(c => c.Product).ToArray();

           comboBoxContainer.Items.AddRange(goods);
           comboBoxContainer.DisplayMember = "Product";
           comboBoxContainer.ValueMember = "Id";
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
    }
```

Comment: What is the type and value of `selected.Container` and what is the data of `comboBoxContainer`? If it's not simple items (like `int`/`string`) do they both come from the same source?

Comment: Can you show us the `ProductList_Variables` implementation and how you fill the `comboBoxContainer`?

Comment: @RolandBär and nvoigt, post updated with your enquiries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems your comboBoxContainer is filled with objects, not with strings so when you assign you should match the object.

Try replacing your line

```
        comboBoxContainer.SelectedItem = selected.Container;
```

as follows

```
        comboBoxContainer.SelectedItem =
            comboBoxContainer.Items.OfType<ProductList_Variables>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Container == selected.Container);
```

Answer (score 0):

When your property Container contains the value (the property Id of your data element of the comboBoxContainer), you can use

```
comboBoxContainer.SelectedValue = selected.Container;
```